# How repeat a row in MySQL resultset for specified times?

Tags: mysql, set, record, resultset, repeat

I've a MySQL table like this:

```
-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| id (int primary key) | count (int) |
-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

Assume that this table is filled with these values:

```
1,1
2,2
3,2
4,3
```

I need to create a view of this table that repeats every row as number of count column, for instance for above data, view would contains this information:

```
1,1
2,1
2,2
3,1
3,2
4,1
4,2
4,3
```

Comment: doing this in the database would be clumsy... just do it on the presentation layer, outside SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
drop table if exists my_test;

create table my_test (
id int not null auto_increment primary key,
`count` int)
engine = myisam;

insert into my_test (`count`) values (1),(2),(2),(3);

delimiter //
drop procedure if exists recurrences //
create procedure recurrences()
begin
declare a,b int;
declare i int default 1;
declare finite int default 0;
declare curs cursor for select id,`count` from my_test;
declare continue handler for not found set finite = 1;
drop table if exists tmp;
create temporary table tmp (id int,cnt int);
open curs;
my_loop:loop
fetch curs into a,b;
if finite = 1 then
leave my_loop;
end if;
while i <= b do
insert into tmp (id,cnt) values (a,i);
set i = i + 1;
end while;
set i = 1;
end loop;
close curs;
select * from tmp;
end //
delimiter ;

call recurrences();


+------+------+
| id   | cnt  |
+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |
|    2 |    1 |
|    2 |    2 |
|    3 |    1 |
|    3 |    2 |
|    4 |    1 |
|    4 |    2 |
|    4 |    3 |
+------+------+
8 rows in set (0.44 sec)
```

First thing I've thought but I don't like execution time. ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as a I told I need a VIEW and NOT A STORED PROCEDURE to do this!

Comment: I don't think it's possible without creating the view within the stored procedure.